# How do I properly use an action hook to enqueue my CSS file in WordPress through using functions.php?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have been trying to get this code to work in my child theme's `functions.php` file in order to properly enqueue my custom CSS file to my template file/page called "dashboard". From what I understand, the `functions.php` file is loaded before the main query, so I am using an action hook with a callback that is shown below. But it just doesn't seem to work. Much help would be appreciated.

*functions.php*

```
add_action('get_header', function() {
    if(is_page('dashboard')) {

        function enqueue_style() {
          wp_enqueue_style( 'dashboard-css', 'https://myurl.com/wp-content/themes/astra-child/css/dashboard.css', false ); 
        }

        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_style' );
    }
});
```

*dashboard.php*

```
<?php /*Template Name: User Dashboard*/?>
<head> 

</head>
<body>
<p>this is my dashboard</p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try code like this in `functions.php` file.

```
function enqueue_style() {
    global $wp_styles, $wp_scripts;
    $protocol = is_ssl() ? 'https' : 'http';
    if(is_page('dashboard')) {
         // Register 
         wp_register_style('dashboard-css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/dashboard.css');
         // Enqueue
         wp_enqueue_style('dashboard-css'); 
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_style');
```

Comment: It did not work as well. Could it possibly be with the theme I am using? It is Astra.

Comment: I also checked to see if the CSS file was registered using ```wp_style_is('dashboard-css')``` in the template file using an if statement and it was false.